# Performance related issue with network connection

Tags: codenameone

1st screen:

```
@Override
protected void postMain(Form f) {
    for (Map<String, Object> element : connectionGroup.responses) {
        String id = (String) element.get("id");
        String tableName = (String) element.get("name");
        String tableImg = (String) element.get("tablelogo");
        String clubcharterdate = (String) element.get("clubcharterdate");
        String total_members = (String) element.get("total_members");

        Container singleRowContainerr = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Container childContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        singleRowContainerr.add(childContainer);

        Label shadow = new Label(" ");
        singleRowContainerr.add(shadow);

        TextArea nameLabel = new TextArea(tableName.toUpperCase());

        Label charterDate = new Label("Charter date: " + clubcharterdate);

        Label totalno = new Label("No. of member: " + total_members);
        Container dataContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY((nameLabel), charterDate, totalno);

        childContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseMiddle(dataContainer));

        Label tableIcon = new Label();
        AllUrl allUrl = new AllUrl();
        String name = tableImg.substring(0, tableImg.lastIndexOf("."));
        Image a = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholderForTable, "tablelogo" + name, allUrl.minuteTableImgUrl + name + ".png", URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
        tableIcon.setIcon(a);
        childContainer.add(BorderLayout.WEST, tableIcon);

        Button hidee = new Button();
        singleRowContainerr.add(hidee);
        hidee.setHidden(true);
        singleRowContainerr.setLeadComponent(hidee);
        wrapContainerSingleTable.add(singleRowContainerr);

        hidee.addActionListener((e) -> {
            detailId = hidee.getName();
            detailTableName = hidee.getUIID();
            showForm("Detail", null);
        });
    }
}
```

2nd screen:

```
protected void postDetail(Form f) {
    f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Container memberContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.add(memberContainer);

    for (int i = 0; i < dc.response.size(); i++) {
        HashMap hm = (HashMap) dc.response.get(i);
        //members lists
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> membersResponse = (ArrayList) hm.get("members");
        for (Map<String, Object> element : membersResponse) {
            String profile_img = (String) element.get("profile_img");
             Image img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "memberImage" + profile_img, au.profileImgUrl + "sm_" + profile_img, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
             Label icon = new Label(img);
             f.add(icon);
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to detail page(2nd screen) from main page(1st screen) before all the images in the main page are loaded, the detail page images are not loaded until all the main screen images are loaded. I know this by seeing the results in the output.
For eg:Although I am in 2nd screen already, only after all the links of 1st screen are loaded, the links of 2nd screen are seen.

```
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://roundtablenepal.org.np//uploads/mobile/12.png to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://roundtablenepal.org.np//uploads/mobile/RT.png to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://roundtablenepal.org.np//uploads/mobile/RT1.png to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
// and all the image links of 1st screen one by one,
// then only the link of 2nd screen are seen and the page load 
//as soon as 2nd screen link starts appearing
```

Then only the links of the images in detail page are seen in the output. It makes the app slower initially. Once all the images are kept into cache, there is no problem though. I have this same problem in real devices too. Everybody who use the app for the 1st time says app is slow. Isn't it possible in codenameone that as soon as I go to one screen from other, all the processes and networks of previous pages are cancelled out and new process/network of current screen is loaded? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`URLImage` is simple and simplistic, it only aware that an image is showing and can thus start fetching it. It has no awareness of the form you are in or whether you no longer need an image.

I know some developers use broadsword tricks like shutting down the network manager but this can backfire with corrupt half downloaded data and odd edge cases that only happen on the device...

A more proper solution is to avoid `URLImage` in complex cases such as these and use custom code that is aware of your application. That's why we have methods to download images in `ConnectionRequest` you can use those and only add the next image once the previous image finished downloading. This is useful as it will allow you to control the process of downloading the images in parallel.

Notice you can also increase the network thread count in the `init(Object)` method by invoking:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().updateThreadCount(2);
```